# How to apply ripple effect to BottomSheets in Android

Tags: android, material-design

I am trying to apply a Material Design ripple effect to the items in a bottom sheet, similar to how selecting an item in a listview would create a ripple effect. Not sure how to style the bottom sheet to allow for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the view background with the relevant attribute, e.g:

```
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

You'll also have to set the view as clickable to let the system know to listen to click events.

```
android:clickable="true"
```

Be aware that for listview items, the "clickable" attribute isn't required and the ripple effect is set as default.